# React Native - How to see what's stored in AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I save some items to `AsyncStorage` in React Native and I am using chrome debugger and iOS simulator.

Without react native, using regular web development `localStorage`, I was able to see the stored `localStorage` items under `Chrome Debugger > Resources > Local Storage`

Any idea how can I view the React Native `AsyncStorage` stored items?

Comment: Not sure if such tools exist, i usually just query it and pass a callback to log it. `AsyncStorage.getItem('thing').then((res) => console.log(res))`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do now, but trying to see if there is a visual way to see everything in storage.

Comment: Drop in UI component https://github.com/vczero/rn-cook

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use reactotron i think it has Async Storage explorer ;)
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

[image]

Comment: very nice tools

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for sharing this tool. Oh, for other greens like myself, make sure you have a `AsyncStorage.getItem(item);`

Comment: Hi @tmehta2442 I am not getting any log of async storage in with reactotron. can you please post how can i get all the async storage logs?

I have done use(asyncStorage()) in my reactotron config.

Comment: @gamingumar I might be late but I have used Reactotron custom commands to do just that:
`Reactotron.onCustomCommand('show_async_storage', () =>{
     //here you could log all the async storage as needed
})`

To do the actual logging you could use @skantus answer. Here is a video explaining custom commands on Reactotron [video](https://youtu.be/UiPo9A9k7xc?t=1334)

Comment: I also created custom commands to set and remove items. The docs aren't clear on that, but you can add parameters to them. Just add `handler: params => AsyncStorage.removeItem(params.key),
  args: [{name: 'key',type: ArgType.String}`

Answer (score 95):

[React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/debugger-integration.md#debugging-tips) has this built in.

Just call `showAsyncStorageContentInDev()` in the RND console and you'll be able to see a dump of your app's storage.

Answer (score 26):

Following should work,

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
  AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (error, stores) => {
    stores.map((result, i, store) => {
      console.log({ [store[i][0]]: store[i][1] });
      return true;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to quickly check something and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

I have created a helper method to log all Storage in a single object (more clean to log for example in Reactotron):

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export function logCurrentStorage() {
  AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((keyArray) => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(keyArray).then((keyValArray) => {
      let myStorage: any = {};
      for (let keyVal of keyValArray) {
        myStorage[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1]
      }

      console.log('CURRENT STORAGE: ', myStorage);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Quite Helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

react native debugger
right click on free space
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30572157)

Comment: RND 0.13.0 prints this info to the Console tab.

Comment: when i click "log asyncstorage content" nothing happen, no new log in console. where this log is printed ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

With [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) you can do this:

```JavaScript
const dumpRaw = () => {
  return AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(keys => {
    return Promise.reduce(keys, (result, key) => {
      return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(value => {
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
      });
    }, {});
  });
};

dumpRaw().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: since you are using arrow function you can use shorthand arrow function: 
instead of `a => {return b=>{return c}}` you can do `a=>b=>c`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late, but none of these solutions fit for me. 
On android, with Android Studio open file explorer then go to ***data/data/your_package_name***
Inside you should have a folder called ***database*** and inside a file ***RKStorage***.

This file is a SQLite3 file so get your favorite SQLite explorer and explore. If you want one this one does the job : [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const printAsyncStorage = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (error, stores) => {
      let asyncStorage = {}
      stores.map((result, i, store) => {
        asyncStorage[store[i][0]] = store[i][1]
      });
      console.table(asyncStorage)
    });
  });
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfeim.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find Reactotron to have any type of pretty printing enabled and it's also brutally latent so I just wrote a simple function using lodash. You could use underscore too.

Assuming you have a static mapping of all your keys...

```
const keys = {
  key1: 'key1',
  key2: 'key2'
}

export function printLocalStorage() {
  _.forEach(keys, (k, v) => {
    localStore.getAllDataForKey(v).then(tree => {
      console.log(k) // Logs key above the object
      console.log(tree) // Logs a pretty printed JSON object
    })
  })
}
```

It's not performant but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can Define function to get all keys by using async and await

```
    getAllkeys = () => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      let items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
      resolve(items)
    } catch (error) {
      reject(new Error('Error getting items from AsyncStorage: ' + error.message))
    }
  });
}


    somefunc = async () => {
    try {
    var items = await getAllkeys();
    var someItems = items.filter(function (result, i, item) {
          // do filtering stuff
          return item;
    });
    // do something with filtered items 
    } catch (error) {
    // do something with your error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@trajano/async-storage-dump-and-load-) that shows this and also performs a "load".  So it is useful for doing a dump of the contents and storing it to a file and loading it up later.

Here are they parts.

```
const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
const data = stores.reduce(
  (acc, row) => ({ ...acc, [row[0]]: row[1] }),
  {}
);

// data now contains a JSONable Javascript object that contains all the data
```

This ammends the data in the AsyncStorage from a JSON string.

```
// sample is a JSON string
const data = JSON.parse(sample);
const keyValuePairs = Object.entries(data)
  .map(([key, value]) => [key, value])
  .reduce((acc, row) => [...acc, row], []);
await AsyncStorage.multiSet(keyValuePairs);
```