# Can't persist react-native redux state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, persistence, redux-persist

In my react-native app, I am trying to persist my redux state into local storage and load it back when the app restarts, with using https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist. There are many tutorials which doesn't say anything different than the offical github page. I've tried many times but I continue to lose my data when I turn off the app and on again. Here is how my code looks like:

```
// store.js
import React from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux';

import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import rootReducer from '../reducer/index';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {persistor, store};
```

```
// app.js

import {store, persistor} from "./store";

// render method returns
<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    // main react-navigation component
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

```
// reducer/index.js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import language from './language'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    language,
    ...
});

export default reducers;
```

Data is lost when I turn off and on again the app or refresh retro server with r on the command screen. What can be the reason? I am also open to any other solution than redux-persist library.

Comment: Have you tried to persist state per state instead of the whole store?

Comment: @AndréPinto No I didn't, how can I do that?

Comment: Almost the same as documentation, you do it inside your combine reducers adding like this:  

https://prnt.sc/yedee6

Comment: @AndréPinto If I understand correctly this is what you suggest me: In the combineReducers method, instead of putting e.g. the reducer called language above in my code, I put `{language: persistReducer(persistConfig, language)}`.  Unfortunately I still lose my data on restarts :(.

Comment: You may be able to investigate whether the data is being saved in your browser by going into inspect element and looking at the cookies/saved data.

Comment: @shn It is a react-native mobile application.

Comment: Shoot my bad, there must be some debugging tools that let you investigate internal storage.

Comment: @shn Yes it is stored in the local storage actually. I used this one to check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54178588/8739916. But I didn't get why it doesn't load data back when the app restarts :/

Comment: sorry for the delay, I am available to try to help you via discord after 7pm GMT -3 -> Andre Pinto#7614

Comment: @AndréPinto I decided to use AsyncStorage only for storing the data in local storage. This also works fine and it wasn't really to much work. Thank you for your help offering.